# iosでベクターデータを描画するときの座標系

Tags: swift, ios, swift2, swift3

myApp（CAD系） for Windowsで作成したベクターデータで
0.01ミリ単位で保存されています。

これをios上で描画することになったのですが、
Quartz 2D,Core Graficsなどを使えばよいみたいなことを聞きました。

座標系などがわかりません。

Windowsでは、論理座標系をデバイスコンテキストに設定できたので、
描画する際は意識はしませんでしたが、同じような考えを持つのでしょうか。

また、なにか参考となる資料等があれば教えてください。
iosプラットフォームでの開発はしたことがありません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iOSにおける描画と印刷のガイド](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/DrawingPrintingiOS.pdf)（PDF書類）
[Quartz 2D プログラミングガイド](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/drawingwithquartz2d.pdf)（PDF書類）

いずれも、Appleの文書です。ネット上で見つかるCore GraphicsとQuartz 2Dに関する情報の元ネタです。C言語とObjective-Cをベースにした解説なので、Swiftへの翻訳にとまどうかもしれませんが、ネット上の情報とうまく組み合わせて学習してください。

「myApp（CAD系） for Windows」が、PDF書き出しに対応しているとしたら、話はかんたんになります。Core Graphicsは、PDFデータを直接取り込みできます。

コンテキストや座標系の話は、紹介した文書の中に解説があります。それを参考にしてください。

Core Graphicsの描画の例を示します。`UIView`のサブクラスを作り、そこに描画します。
（Swift 3）

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class DrawView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // UIViewのグラフィックスコンテキストを取得。
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return
        }
        // 多角形のパスを作成。
        // 頂点をポイント。
        context.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: 40.0, y: 30.0),
                                   CGPoint(x: 80.0, y: 20.0),
                                   CGPoint(x: 120.0, y: 50.0),
                                   CGPoint(x: 60.0, y: 70.0),
                                   CGPoint(x: 20.0, y: 90.0),
                                   CGPoint(x: 50.0, y: 50.0)])
        // パスを閉じる。
        context.closePath()
        // 塗りつぶしの色を決める。
        context.setFillColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
        // パスを塗りつぶし。
        context.fillPath()

        // 楕円を描画。
        context.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 100.0, width: 100.0, height: 60.0))
        // 線の太さを決める。
        context.setLineWidth(4.0)
        // 線の色を決める。
        context.setStrokeColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        // パスを線画。
        context.strokePath()
    }

}
```

クラス名の冒頭に`@IBDesignable`が付いているのは、Storyboard/Interface Builderの編集画面に表示するためのものです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]